# Destroying luks header on dm-crypt linux

Tags: linux, cryptography, crypt, luks

**I am trying to destroy the luks header on one of my logical volume data1, I am still able to read the file inside data1 after I delete the luks header. I suppose it should not be the case right? Can someone help me in understanding this case?**

#### lsblk output

```
NAME                                            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                               8:0    0 894.2G  0 disk
├─sda1                                            8:1    0   500M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                                            8:2    0 893.8G  0 part
  ├─vg0-root                                    251:0    0 758.7G  0 lvm
  │ └─luks-45f803e5-3c17-4aaf-a9ad-d66c8b5458de 251:2    0 758.7G  0 crypt /
  ├─vg0-swap                                    251:1    0    75G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
  ├─vg0-data3                                   251:3    0    20G  0 lvm
  │ └─luks-6e168d35-26dc-429c-a3d6-8cb4f1c1d39e 251:7    0    20G  0 crypt /data3
  ├─vg0-data2                                   251:4    0    20G  0 lvm
  │ └─luks-75727dd1-a332-423d-8c37-4cedf9cbe83c 251:8    0    20G  0 crypt /data2
  └─vg0-data1                                   251:5    0    20G  0 lvm
    └─luks-cf2d9729-2d1b-48b8-8502-dea937ef602f 251:6    0    20G  0 crypt /data1
```

#### Luksdump output to check if the luks header is exists:

```
-130-sapam@test-host:~ $ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/vg0-data1
LUKS header information for /dev/mapper/vg0-data1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha256
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      9f e7 1a b3 0e fb 4e bc 6d 1b 9e 46 f8 bd 15 22 ea 04 6e c3
MK salt:        83 5e 90 5b b3 a1 c5 a5 d4 22 a0 3e 23 25 51 50
                fc cd a8 ac db 9f d0 a8 8b 81 6e 9a 92 1f d8 d3
MK iterations:  43750
UUID:           cf2d9729-2d1b-48b8-8502-dea937ef602f

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             439102
    Salt:                   f1 6d 23 b0 b7 ee fc 09 8c 6b 92 ef b2 17 ef d9
                            0c 83 64 29 bf bc 98 3f f6 93 4b 45 06 49 a9 21
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
```

#### Destroying the luks header:

```
-130-sapam@test-host:~ $ sudo dd bs=512 count=4096 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/vg0-data1
4096+0 records in
4096+0 records out
2097152 bytes (2.1 MB) copied, 0.00444235 s, 472 MB/s
-0-sapam@test-host:~ $ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/mapper/vg0-data1
-1-sapam@test-host:~ $
```

#### I still able to read the file inside /data1/

```
-1-sapam@test-host:~ $ cat /data1/foo
james
-0-sapam@test-host:~ $
```

From my understanding is once the header is destroyed, the /data1 should not be able to read right?

Comment: a few ponters... is the drive cache written to disk? (you are lacking a sync to be sure the buffers are flushed) does the daemon cache the header data in ram? (it certainly will not re-read and decrypt the key for every io-op)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are destroying already mounted partition.

Encryption/decryption keys are hold in the memory while the partition is mounted. You should unmout your LUKS partition first:

```
# umount /data1
```

and then erase the LUKS header. You won't be able to mount it again.

Please note `cryptsetup` utility has a command to erase LUKS header:

```
# cryptsetup luksErase /dev/mapper/vg0-data1
```

The advantage of this operation is that you can restore LUKS header from the backup if you done it before.

from `cryptsetup(8)`:

```
       erase <device>
       luksErase <device>

              Erase all keyslots and make the LUKS container permanently inac‐
              cessible.  You do not need to provide any password for this  op‐
              eration.

              WARNING: This operation is irreversible.
```

Answer (score 1):

While `luksErase` is nice to wipe the keyslots area, note that it doesn't actually destroy the entire LUKS Header. It leaves the metadata intact.

I submitted a [feature request](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/544) asking for the `luksErase` command to have the ability to wipe the plaintext metadata in the header as well, but the developer rejected & closed it :(

## LUKS Header Shredder

You can use the following BASH script to find every LUKS device on the system, wipe the headers, and shutdown the machine.

> **Disclaimer**
> The script below contains experimental software that may or may not lead to corruption or total **permanent deletion of some or all of your data**. I cannot be responsible for any data loss that has occurred as a result of following this guide.
>
> The contents of this answer is provided openly and is licensed under the CC-BY-SA license. The software included in this guide is licensed under the GNU GPLv3 license. All content here is consistent with the limitations of liabilities outlined in its respective licenses.
>
> I highly recommend that any experiments with the script included in this answer is used exclusively on a disposable machine containing no valuable data.
>
> If data loss is a concern for you, then leave now and do not proceed. You have been warned.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

################################################################################
# File:    buskill-selfdestruct.sh
# Purpose: Self-destruct trigger script for BusKill Kill Cord
#          For more info, see: https://buskill.in/
# WARNING: THIS IS EXPERIMENTAL SOFTWARE THAT IS DESIGNED TO CAUSE PERMANENT,
#          COMPLETE AND IRREVERSIBLE DATA LOSS!
# Note   : This script will *not* execute unless it's passed the '--yes'
#          argument. Be sure to test this trigger before depending on it!
# Authors: Michael Altfield <michael@buskill.in>
# Created: 2020-03-11
# Updated: 2020-03-11
# Version: 0.1
################################################################################

############
# SETTINGS #
############

BUSKILL_LOCK='/usr/local/bin/buskill-lock.sh'
[ -f ${BUSKILL_LOCK} ] || echo "ERROR: Unable to find buskill-lock.sh"

CRYPTSETUP=`which cryptsetup` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find cryptsetup"
LS=`which ls` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find ls"
CAT=`which cat` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find cat"
GREP=`which grep` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find grep"
ECHO=`which echo` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find echo"
AWK=`which awk` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find awk"
HEAD=`which head` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find head"
LSBLK=`which lsblk` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find lsblk"
OD=`which od` || echo "ERROR: Unable to find od"

##############
# ROOT CHECK #
##############

# re-run as root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    exec sudo /bin/bash "$0" "$@"
fi

###########
# CONFIRM #
###########

# for safety, exit if this script is executed without a '--yes' argument
${ECHO} "${@}" | ${GREP} '\--yes' &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ${ECHO} "WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING"
    ${ECHO} "================================================================================"
    ${ECHO} "WARNING: THIS IS EXPERIMENTAL SOFTWARE THAT IS DESIGNED TO CAUSE PERMANENT,  COMPLETE AND IRREVERSIBLE DATA LOSS!"
    ${ECHO} "================================================================================"
    ${ECHO} "WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING"
    ${ECHO}
    ${ECHO} "cowardly refusing to execute without the '--yes' argument for your protection. If really you want to proceed with damaging your system, retry with the '--yes' argument"
    exit 1
fi

###########################
# (DELAYED) HARD SHUTDOWN #
###########################

# The most secure encrypted computer is an encrypted computer that is *off*
# This is our highest priority; initiate a hard-shutdown to occur in 5 minutes regardless
# of what happens later in this script

nohup sleep 60 && echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger &
nohup sleep 61 && shutdown -h now &
nohup sleep 62 && poweroff --force --no-sync &

###############
# LOCK SCREEN #
###############

# first action: lock the screen!
${BUSKILL_LOCK} &

#####################
# WIPE LUKS VOLUMES #
#####################

# overwrite luks headers
${ECHO} "INFO: shredding LUKS header (plaintext metadata and keyslots with encrypted master decryption key)"
writes=''
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $( ${LSBLK} --list --output 'PATH,FSTYPE' | ${GREP} 'crypt' ); do

    device="`${ECHO} \"${line}\" | ${AWK} '{print \$1}'`"
    ${ECHO} -e "\t${device}"

    ###########################
    # OVERWRITE LUKS KEYSLOTS #
    ###########################

    # erases all keyslots, making the LUKS container "permanently inaccessible"
    ${CRYPTSETUP} luksErase --batch-mode "${device}" || ${HEAD} --bytes 20M /dev/urandom > ${device} &

    # store the pid of the above write tasks so we can try to wait for it to
    # flush to disk later -- before triggering a brutal hard-shutdown
    writes="${writes} $!"

    #####################################
    # OVERWRITE LUKS PLAINTEXT METADATA #
    #####################################

    luksVersion=`${OD} --skip-bytes 6 --read-bytes 2 --format d2 --endian=big --address-radix "n" "${device}"`

    # get the end byte to overwrite. For more info, see:
    # https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227359/how-to-determine-start-and-end-bytes-of-luks-header
    if [[ $luksVersion -eq 1 ]]; then
        # LUKS1: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf

        # in LUKS1, the whole header ends at 512 * the `payload-offset`
        # this is actually more than we need (includes keyslots), but
        # it's the fastest/easiest to bound to fetch in LUKS1
        payloadOffset=`${OD} --skip-bytes 104 --read-bytes 4 --format d4 --endian=big --address-radix "n" "${device}"`
        luksEndByte=$(( 512 * ${payloadOffset} ))

    elif [[ $luksVersion -eq 2 ]]; then
        # LUKS2: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/LUKS2-docs/blob/master/luks2_doc_wip.pdf

        # in LUKS2, the end of the plaintext metadata area is twice the
        # size of the `hdr_size` field
        hdr_size=`${OD} --skip-bytes 8 --read-bytes 8 --format d8 --endian=big --address-radix "n" "${device}"`
        luksEndByte=$(( 2 * ${hdr_size} ))

    else
        # version unclear; just overwrite 20 MiB
        luksEndByte=20971520

    fi
        
    # finally, shred that plaintext metadata; we do this in a new file descriptor
    # to prevent bash from truncating if ${device} is a file
    exec 5<> "${device}"
    ${HEAD} --bytes "${luksEndByte}" /dev/urandom >&5 &
    writes="${writes} $!"
    exec 5>&-
done

#######################
# WAIT ON DISK WRITES #
#######################

# wait until all the write tasks above have completed
# note: do *not* put quotes around this arg or the whitespace will break wait
wait ${writes}

# clear write buffer to ensure headers overwrites are actually synced to disks
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

#################################
# WIPE DECRYPTION KEYS FROM RAM #
#################################

# suspend each currently-decrypted LUKS volume
${ECHO} "INFO: removing decryption keys from memory"
for device in $( ${LS} -1 "/dev/mapper" ); do

    ${ECHO} -e "\t${device}";
    ${CRYPTSETUP} luksSuspend "${device}" &

    # clear page caches in memory (again)
    sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

done

#############################
# (IMMEDIATE) HARD SHUTDOWN #
#############################

# do whatever works; this is important.
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger &
sleep 1
shutdown -h now &
sleep 1
poweroff --force --no-sync &

# exit cleanly (lol)
exit 0
```

##### Sources

1. [LUKS Header Shredder (BusKill Self-Destruct Trigger)](https://www.buskill.in/luks-self-destruct/)
2. https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-linux/blob/master/triggers/buskill-selfdestruct.sh

Answer (score 0):

To completely get rid of the LUKS headers, use `cryptsetup luksErase` to remove all of the keys per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60597280/3256996) from @vojta-myslivec and then use `wipefs --all <device>` to erase the remaining LUKS header.